# How to mask URL's like cloudapp, so users can showoff our data on "their" server

Tags: php

I'm planning to build a webapp where users can show off their data. I want our users to be able to show it off on their own site, just like cloudapp. You can set your own domain name, but still use the application's hosting service.

So my service is `http://example.com/showoff` but I want users to have the option to use `http://showoff.example.net` for their data.

I'm planning on doing it in PHP, but i'm open for suggestions if it comes to building this kind of service.

Comment: Doing username.yoursite.com is easier to implement than yoursite.usersite.com - you have control of *.yoursite.com, whereas the customer has control of *.usersite.com. Doing it on the domain that they control means that you have to give them complex instructions on how to set up a CNAME entry on their DNS server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume your domain is "showoff.com" and their domain is "acme.com"

You have two basic options: "showoff.acme.com" or "acme.showoff.com". I have done this both ways.

For "showoff.acme.com":

- The customer will need to set up a CNAME entry pointing to showoff.com in their DNS. *Explaining to the customer how to do this is not trivial, and doesn't make much business sense unless you have a small, high-paying customer base.*
- You will need to configure an Apache virtualhost to answer all requests to all domains (not just showoff.com)
- You cannot use SSL unless you configure a virtualhost and IP and certificate for each individual customer. (A pain!)

For "acme.showoff.com":

- You will need a [wildcard DNS record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record) to point *.showoff.com to your server's IP (whether this is easy depends on your DNS provider); if you are unable to do this, you will need to create a DNS record for each customer.
- You will need to configure an Apache virtualhost to answer all requests to *.showoff.com
- You can use a [wildcard SSL certificate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_SSL_certificate) for *.showoff.com

In both scenarios, in your PHP you can find out what domain was requested with `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`. You will want to check this against your database of recognized domains, to determine which customer's data to show.

As you can see, most of the work is in DNS and Apache; it doesn't really matter whether you use PHP or some other language.

Answer (score 1):

They have to point a DNS entry for showoff.usersite.com to your server. You can read that from the $_SERVER variables and off you go! Point another domain to your site and try: print_R($_SERVER) and you will see the domainname pointing to you.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reaction, do you have some info where i can read more about this?

Comment: Mark just explained the possible implementation, as I read you question correctly you need the first list, meaning that you don't have to do much on server settings. Though one thing should be considered: You need a dedicated IP.